# PDFTron Web Viewer in ASP.NET or HTML page - loading pdf or xod displays error

Tags: asp.net, html, pdftron

Uisng PDFTron Web Viewer in ASP.NET or HTML page to display PDF or XOD file, I receive the error as - "Failed to load resource file. This could be due to an incorrect worker path or unsupported .res mime type on the server."

```
<script>
$(function () {
            var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
            var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
                path: 'lib',
                type: 'html5',
                documentType: "pdf",
                initialDoc: "lib/GettingStarted.pdf",
                config: '',
                streaming: false, 
                enableAnnotations: false,
                enableOfflineMode: false,
                enableReadOnlyMode: true       
            }, viewerElement);
        });
</script>
```

The console window of the browser shows as below:

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
View
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
View
SCRIPT7016: Use of XMLHttpRequest with the synchronous flag set to true is deprecated due to its impact on user-perceived site performance.
browserLink (37,85652)
SCRIPT7015: Setting withCredentials attribute for synchronous XMLHttpRequest is deprecated
View
asm.js has been disabled as the script debugger is connected. Disconnect the debugger to enable asm.js.
PDFNetC.js
HTTP range requests not supported. Switching to streaming mode.
ControlUtils.js (170,25)
Error: error.ResourceLoadError
PDFReaderControl.js (14,13)
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - http://localhost:63936/lib/html5/pdf/pdfnet.res
Could not use incremental download for url /lib/GettingStarted.pdf. Reason: Byte ranges are not supported by the server.
CoreControls.js (669,43)
asm.js has been disabled as the script debugger is connected. Disconnect the debugger to enable asm.js.
PDFNetC.js
Error: No response from frame: #\35 697
browserLink (363,16590)
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "No response from frame: #\35 697",
      message: "No response from frame: #\35 697",
      name: "Error",
      stack: "Error: No response from frame: #\35 697
   at A (http://localhost:56824/e61cf52526d049168d3be50fd1b6a801/browserLink:363:5795)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:56824/e61cf52526d049168d3be50fd1b6a801/browserLink:363:21639)"
   }

SCRIPT0: could not load memory initializer PDFNetC.js.mem
PDFNetC.js (36,1)
```

Comment: 404 just means not found - I'm not familiar with the subject matter but please check the location exists.

Comment: @Booboobeaker : yes the file exists on the server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add following to your web.config, make sure remove and add some of these in case you are running from IISExpress.

```
<system.webServer>    
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".js" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" />
  <!-- PDFViewer -->
  <!--Remove statement for each extension is for running it on IIS Express-->
  <remove fileExtension=".json" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".res" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".nmf" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pexe" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mem" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".brotli" mimeType="text/plain" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Using the web.config changes suggested by you, the PDF files are now displayed successfully in the Web Viewer control. However, the XOD files are still not displayed. Please suggest.

Comment: For XOD files, so I added `code`<mimeMap fileExtension=".xod" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument" />

Comment: .mem should instead be application/octet-stream for version 8 of the webviewer